# Memory warning & crash issue

Tags: iphone, memory-management, crash, memory-warning, ios6.0

I have developed application using ARC. In one of my UIViewController there are number of sub controllers (Like Buttons, Labels, Textfields, Textview, Scrollview) which all are having its IBOutlet. Here issue is that,I am using iOS 6.0.

With iOS 6.0 **viewDidUnload** method is deprecated. So at the time of **Pop**, this method is not called. I have checked with **"product--> profile--> allocation"** here whenever this controller is pushed in the navigation stack it increases the live memory Bytes but on pop Memory bytes don't decrease. Because of this after using an application for some time I am getting **Received Memory Warning** & application is going to be crashed in random instances.

Is there any alternative way to handle this kind of backend memory management issue.

Comment: check your dealloc method .and check is it called.

Comment: and check your view all variable released

Comment: @JohnPatel hi you should check this link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393226/how-it-works-didreceivememorywarning-for-ios-6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First check in `.h`  file that you property-sythesized with retain or not if with retain then set strong instead of retain like bellow..

```
@property ( nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *yourTextField;;
```

Comment: I have not used property for all the controllers.

Comment: @JohnPatel hey check out the answer from this link same like your issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496029/ios-arc-not-freeing-memory hope its helpful to you...

Comment: @JohnPatel also check out that some where you not used `autorelease` or `release` keyword if yes then remove that lines.

Comment: @paras-joshi...Please do let me check with all this criteria.